# Returned state value is not updated

Tags: swift, swiftui

Using the method getAmount() in the snippet below, I've tried to return user input to another view but every time I call getAmount() from another view, the value returned is "0.0" though I'm not sure why - though the view Text(amount) always shows up-to-date user input.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TableRow: View {
    var label: String
    @State var amount = "";
    var indent: CGFloat = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Spacer()
                .frame(width: indent)
            Text(label)
            Spacer()
            Text("£")
            TextField(String(format: "%.2f", amount), text: $amount)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                .frame(width: 75.0)
            Text(amount)
        }
    }

    func getAmount() -> Double {
//        print("Amount is \(amount)")
        return NumberFormatter().number(from: amount)?.doubleValue ?? 1.0
    }
}
```

Comment: You generally shouldn't call methods of another view in SwiftUI to get values back. There are patterns that you should us, if you need data to flow "up" the view hierarchy to a parent - e.g. via a `@Binding`

Comment: Agree with @NewDev, you can use a more “global” variable and manipulate it from different views using an observable object with a binding var. slightly different than a state var. lots of documentation and examples regarding how to implement observable objects. Just don’t forget to add the object to the environment when instantiating the view.

Comment: ThANKS NewDev and Lkabo, both your comments guided me in the right direction and I got everything working!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're probably unknowingly calling the method from a copy of your view and not the actual view. Structures are value types in Swift, not reference types, meaning if you pass them around they get copied instead of passed by reference like classes. You might look into that. Otherwise I would need to see where you're calling the function to help more.